# How can I open kdb file with ssl certificate for MQ?

Tags: ssl, message-queue, certificate

IBM MQ uses some strange to me certificate format with kdb extension.

How can I open it and change its validity date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *IBM Key Management* tool (aka Ikeyman) for this purpose. Yous should get it with MQ installation. Just review [Working with WebSphere MQ TLS and SSL support](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzas.doc/sy11550_.htm) Section of Websphere MQ documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The *IBM Key Management tool* can be from the command line with `strmqikm`

This will allow you to view and modify the key database.

I do not believe you will be able to modify the validity date of a certificate inside the kdb container.  You can import and export certificates with the tool though.